# jQuery - Is it possible to change selectbox's options during cloning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

Is it possible to change `selectbox's` options during cloning?

I am cloning a div with its inner children. Each one of them has a different id every time they get cloned. The original div  contains a select box which gets it's values from the database. 
My question is, is it possible to amend the values of the cloned select boxes so they will not contain the previous selected values? Any tips on how to do this?

What I need is the newly created select boxes won't contain the values of the previous selections.

**Example** if in select box 1 I choose 1 (from a range 1-10) then the value 1 will not appear in the other select boxes

**JS**

```
<script>
document.getElementById('btn_new_service').onclick = duplicate;
var i =0;
function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicator');
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicator" + ++i; // there can only be one element with
    var new_service_ID = 'c_service-'+i;
    var new_vat_ID = 'vat-'+i;
    var new_amount_ID = 'amount-'+i;
    var new_vatamount_ID = 'vat_amount-'+i;
    clone.querySelector('#c_service').setAttribute('id',new_service_ID);
    clone.querySelector('#vat').setAttribute('id',new_vat_ID);
    clone.querySelector('#amount').setAttribute('id',new_amount_ID);
    clone.querySelector('#vat_amount').setAttribute('id',new_vatamount_ID);
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone); 
};
</script>
```

Comment: yes, this is possible, but your question is not very clear

Comment: any tips on how to do that? (ill edit the question)

Comment: What's the link between jQuery and your question ? I see no jQuery here

Comment: Isn't by using jQuery I will be able to do what I am asking? @Apolo

Comment: @noel293 jQuery is a javascript facilitator, everything you can do with jQuery, you can also do it with pure JS

Comment: @noel293 but I don't get your problem, check my answer; I don't have any trouble with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of what's selected and regenerate a select from scratch, this would be easier

```js
const selectClass = "mySelect";
const options = [
  {id: "c_service", name: "c_service"},
  {id: "vat", name: "vat"},
  {id: "amount", name: "amount"},
  {id: "vat_amount", name: "vat_amount"}
];

var id = 0;

function addSelect() {
  // Get selects
  let selects = document.getElementsByClassName(selectClass);
  // Get all selected values
  let selectedOpts = [];
  for (let select of selects) {
    if (select.value != "") {
      selectedOpts.push(select.value);
    }
  }
  // Create the new select
  let select = document.createElement("select");
  select.setAttribute("class",selectClass);
  select.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
  // Get available options
  var avOpts = options.filter(o => selectedOpts.indexOf(o.id) == -1);
  // Create the options
  for (var option of avOpts) {
    id++; 
    let o = document.createElement("option");
    o.setAttribute("id", option.id + id);
    o.innerHTML = option.name;
    select.appendChild(o);
  }
  // Add the select to DOM
  document.getElementById("divToInsertInto").appendChild(select);
}


// add the initial select
addSelect();
// Attach event
document.getElementById('btn_new_service').onclick = addSelect;
```

```html
<button id="btn_new_service">clone</button>

<div id="divToInsertInto">
</div>
```

Comment: No, the script clones everything! What I need is that the selected values will not appear on the next cloned selectboxes

Comment: when you run my code snippet, select a value and then clone, do you have the selected value cloned also ? Because I don't

Comment: i can choose c_service in all the boxes